# Breaking for-each loop on a conditional base

Tags: for-loop, xslt-2.0

I'm new to xslt 2.0, I would like to set the value to a variable in for-each loop only once (means if the value set, I want to come out of the loop).

For now it keep iterating for all the users. I just want to come out of the loop once the value set (immediately after my first attemp). I'm not sure how to break if the value set once.

Can you please help me on the below code ?

XSLT Code:

```
        <xsl:variable name="v_first_name">
            <xsl:for-each select="$emailList/emails/child::*">
                <xsl:variable name="mailid" select="id" />
                <xsl:for-each select="$userList/users/child::*">
                    <xsl:if test="emailid = $mailid">
                        <xsl:if test="firstname eq 'Antony'">

                            <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />

                        </xsl:if>

                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:variable>



        <xsl:if test="$v_first_name != ''">

        <first_name>            
            <xsl:value-of select="$v_first_name" /> 
            </first_name>           
        </xsl:if>
```

XML O/p:

```
        <first_name>AntonyAntonyAntonyAntony</first_name>
```

Expected XML O/P:

```
        <first_name>Antony</first_name>
```

Note1: Please note that I'm using xslt 2.0 and my lists can have duplicates (So Antony can come twice, but I want only once (or unique)).
Note2: I also tried with position(), but couldn't find it work as the condition () can match at any position.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Start with XPath and simply select the nodes you are looking for instead of considering `for-each` a "loop". If you select e.g. `$userList/users/*[emailid = $emailList/emails/*/id]` you select child elements from `users` which have a matching `emailid` in `$emailList/emails/*`.

I am not sure which sense it makes to hard code a first name value and then output it but of course you can select e.g. `$userList/users/*[emailid = $emailList/emails/*/id and firstname  = 'Antony']/lastname`. That gives you a sequence of element nodes, if you want the first use a positional predicate e.g. depending on the structure of your input `$userList/users/*[emailid = $emailList/emails/*/id and firstname  = 'Antony'][1]/lastname` or, of all selected elements `($userList/users/*[emailid = $emailList/emails/*/id and firstname  = 'Antony']/lastname)[1]`.